# I want to do something every time console.log executes. Can I add an event listener?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

I want to do something every time `console.log` executes. Can I add an event listener to console.log or is monkey patching the only approach? If monkey patching is the best approach, how to I monkey patch without creating infinite recursion?

Comment: Yes, you will need to do monkey patching. And instead of "recursively" calling the `console.log` function again, you will need to store a reference to the original function and call that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper function that wraps the behaviour of console.log.
Something like:

```
const logWrapper = (logString) => {
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
    console.log(logString);
}
```

and call that new function instead.
You could also change the definition of console.log, but I wouldn't advise that.